# 'Error: Class 'search_result' is not defined' in custom query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I'm trying to get the result of the query from the database.

```
    $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

 $qb=$em2->createQuery('select count(DISTINCT hotel_id) FROM search_result where request_id=:searchId')->setParameter('searchId',$searchId);

    $result = $qb->getResult();
```

And get error:

> ine 0, col 37 near 'search_result': Error: Class 'search_result' is
>   not defined.

Answer (score 1):

`DQL !== SQL`

Change:

`FROM search_result`

To:

`FROM AppBundle:SearchResult`

Don't look at your table name, but your entity name. Replace `AppBundle:SearchResult` by your real entity name.